# HERE maps JS API 3.1 - Error for style group 'non-collision' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, here-api, tangram

I'm getting this error sometimes when loading a HERE map with the satellite base layer:

```
    Tangram [error]: Error for style group 'non-collision' for tile 13/16/15542/12554/15 Cannot read property 'retain' of undefined: TypeError: Cannot read property 'retain' of undefined
    at https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:259708
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:377:259679
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3508:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:64284:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3507:52)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3267:43)
    at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4006:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3540:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:64275:33)
```

This prevents the tiles from loading at first.
It doesn't happen everytime. About 3 out of 10 page loads. If pan or switch to defaultLayers.vector.normal.map layer it starts to load the tiles correctly.

I'm using Angular 7.2.15 and HERE API 3.1.

I'm initializing the map in the following way:

```
const platform = new H.service.Platform({ apikey: apiKey });
const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

const map = new H.Map(
  elementRef.nativeElement, // elementRef:ElementRef from directive constructor
  defaultLayers.raster.satellite.map,
  {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: 0, lng:0}
  }
);

const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

const ui = new H.ui.UI(map);
const zoomControl = new H.ui.ZoomControl();
ui.addControl('zoom', zoomControl);
```

How can I load the map in satellite view without throwing this errors?

Comment: it definitely sounds like a bug, as that property should never be missing as far as I'm aware of. But in order to debug, it would be very helpful to have a working example. Can you please provide in JSFiddle or whichever way convenient

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue for the behavior could be some HERE JS library being loaded after the web page is loaded. Try if adding the satellite layer later on in the code has a better response.

```
// default map base layer 
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:52.5160, lng:13.3779},
  zoom: 13
});
// set base layer later 
map.setBaseLayer(defaultLayers.raster.satellite.map);
```

Comment: NOT WORKING,  I try your suggest, but error message still there.